# How to fire up a javascript function with Java

Tags: javascript, java, html

I am currently getting some data from a website and I need to use java to fire up a javascript function without clicking the corresponding button on the HTML, the HTML of that button looks like this:

```
<a class="d-info" href="javascript:downXml(12449086,'2.Some Video names');">XML</a>
```

the script is not embedded in this HTML so how to deal with this situation, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

The details that you have provided is not enough but assuming that you're trying selenium or JSoup like library to automate or to scrape the web page details. checkout some selenium automation scripts how that is doing the job. You can pick DOM elements and automate the real scenario.